# Send a collection of java object to native function via JNI and get results back to java

Tags: java, c++, c, struct, java-native-interface

These days I am working on a new application that will be written in java and it will call native dll's functions via JNI.
The main purpose of the application is to receive data from the internet and save it to temporary class objects. Later, when the number of created objects reaches 200, it should convert the data to c structs and pass an array of struct pointers to native dll function.
Native function will perform some calculation and return a new array of structs (results). These structs will have to be converted to java objects and passed to java side.
I have to note that rewriting native code functionality in java is not an option.

Performance is very important and that is the reason why I chose to use JNI.
I have read many posts and came to the conclusion that in order to get a good performance, I will have to minimize the number of calls to JNI layer, and a preferable way will be to pass the data in one batch.

What do you think is the best way to perform this task?
Should I serialize the data to byte array, pass it to the native side and deserialize it to c structs?
Are there any other efficient solutions?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Collecting 200 (Why 200? Why not 42?) objects and passing them to the C code may or may not have the efficiency boost you expect. What about the latency between one object from "the internet" and the next one? Are you sure that this time can't be used for doing the JNI call?

Comment: Custom serializing can be done so that the result of N objects of the same class results in an array of N structs, and this can be passed to and processed by C code "as is", so there won't be any need for "deserialize it to C structs".

Comment: JNI code *can* access Java object data directly. Maybe that's an option?

Comment: ok, "200" is just an example.  Sometimes even more than 10000 objects have to be passed in one call. Native function expects to get many objects each call. Could you please give more information on custom serialization of N objects?

Comment: Kerrek SB: JNI code will still have to convert each objects's field before passing the struct to Native function, isn't it?

Comment: @laune best option, imo.  Native layer would only need to extract the information from the jbyteArray once for each object, rather than pull the data field by field.  Just be aware of byte-order(big-endian vs little-endian)